# Obtain Adobe DPS folio list

Tags: api, adobe-dps

Is there any way to get folio list from adobe DPS publishing server to machine with implemented direct entitlement?
Only method which i know right now is to put that information to my database manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the folio from the fulfilment server the same way the viewer application does.

Call the URL

```
http://edge.adobe-dcfs.com/ddp/issueServer/issues?accountId=xxxx&targetDimension=all
```

using your accountId in the place of xxxx

To get the accountId you need to call this URL http://lighthouse.adobe.com/dps/entitlement and enter your account's login and password there. If you don't want to do that you can open the .ipa file of you iPad app and get the accountId from within the file LibraryConfig.plist. The value is at serviceOptions->fulfillment->loginOptions->accountId.